# How many shortest paths are there between points in a grid with missing points and blocked paths?

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory

there. I encountered a problem finding out the number of shortest paths between points on a grid with missing points or blocked paths, as shown in the following picture (e.g. C and D in question 1 and those in question 2).

I've found the answer to the question about the number of shortest paths on a full gird on StackExchange (Thanks!). But I don't know how to deal with the shortest path issue on grids with missing points and blocked path. How to caculate the shortest paths on "abnormal" grids? Thank you very much for your help!
[image]

Comment: The pencil-work on 2B actually shows the general algorithm you can use.  Is that not your work?

Comment: Thank you but that's not my work. And I don't know what algorithm can be deduced from the numbers written on 2B. Would you please show a formula representing the algorithm?

Comment: There isn't really a formula for the non-regular case. When you were given the solution for the regular grids, didn't they tell you how they found the solution? The same approach will probably work, just give a different answer.

Comment: Is there from a book? If yes, could you please let me know the title of this book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm being used in 2B is as follows.

1. Label the initial point with the number 1.
2. Consider the points which are just one line away (in a correct direction) from one or more previously labelled points. For each such point, $P$ say, add the labels of the adjacent labelled points and make this total the label for $P$.
3. Repeat step 2 until you reach the end point.

Check this out with the helpfully completed example 2B from your exercise.

Comment: Thank you, S. Dolan. I think that's the right way of doing the one in 2A and 2B. Does the method also apply to 1C and 1D?

Comment: Yes (but note that the labels on the bottom row in 1C are incorrect).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it out. By the way, which filed(s) of mathematics do these problems belong to?

Comment: It could be called Combinatorics. More generally, problems of this type tend to be called 'decision mathematics'.

Comment: One of the nice things about maths is the way results in one area can be applied elsewhere. For example, the problems you are studying can be converted into equations and solved by the methods of a topic called Linear Programming.

Comment: Thank you, S. Dolan for letting me know about the mathematics behind these practical problems. I think math is really a very good tool for describing almost everything in the world we live in.